# jQuery double .each looping, help me solve logical issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, calculation

I need to solve some calculations and I'm using an `.each()` loop. I'm populating rows `<tr>` dynamically so I use `.each()` to loop through the table but I can't get different values when I have to sort them by `vat` value.

```js
function callSum(id) {
    var counter = 1;
    var sum = document.getElementById("sum" + id).value;
    var vat = document.getElementById("vat" + id).value;

    $('.sumall').each(function() {

        $('.vatall').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 0) { //if value of VAT is 0 sum it to vatTotalZero
                document.getElementById("vatTotalZero").value = $(this, ".sumall").val; // don't know how to solve this
            } else { //if value of VAT is > 0 sum it to vatTotal
                document.getElementById("vatTotal").value = $(this, ".sumall").val; // don't know how to solve this
            }
            counter++;
        });

    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td class="col-sm-1">
  <input type="text" name="sum[]" id="sum1" onfocus="callSum(1)" class="sumall form-control"/>
  </td>
  <td class="col-sm-1">
  <input type="text" name="vat[]" id="vat1" class="vatall form-control  "/>
  </td>
</tr>

<br><br>
<label>All Sums without VAT (vat 0)</label>
<input type="text" name="vatTotalZero" id="vatTotalZero" class="form-control  "/>

<br><br>
<label>All Sums with VAT (vat > 0)</label>
<input type="text" name="vatTotal" id="vatTotal" class="form-control  "/>
```

Comment: Hey @SiCat, your code left me wondering. It was confusing to review your code. But I don't think that it would be helpful nor smart to tell you the particular issues. IMHO it would be much better and straight forward if you update your question. Just describe with very simple words what you actually want to achieve. regards

Answer (score 0):

Please see disrciptive comments in the source code.

```js
function callSum(id) {

    var counter = 1,
        sum = document.getElementById("sum" + id).value,
        vat = document.getElementById("vat" + id).value,
        sumallVal;

    $('.sumall').each(function () {

        /* get the value */
        sumallVal = $(this).val();

        $('.vatall').each(function () {

            if ($(this).val() == 0) { //if value of VAT is 0 sum it to vatTotalZero

                //document.getElementById("vatTotalZero").value = $(this, ".sumall").val; // don't know how to solve this
                /* set the value */
                $("#vatTotalZero").val( sumallVal )

            } else { //if value of VAT is > 0 sum it to vatTotal

                //document.getElementById("vatTotal").value = $(this, ".sumall").val; // don't know how to solve this
                /* set the value */
                $("#vatTotal").val( sumallVal )

            }

            counter++;

        });

    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td class="col-sm-1">
        <!-- <input type="text" name="sum[]" id="sum1" onfocus="callSum(1)" class="sumall form-control" /> -->
        <input type="text" name="sum[]" id="sum1" onchange="callSum(1)" class="sumall form-control" />
    </td>
    <td class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="text" name="vat[]" id="vat1" class="vatall form-control  " />
    </td>
</tr>
<br>
<br>
<label>All Sums without VAT (vat 0)</label>
<input type="text" name="vatTotalZero" id="vatTotalZero" class="form-control  " />
<br>
<br>
<label>All Sums with VAT (vat > 0)</label>
<input type="text" name="vatTotal" id="vatTotal" class="form-control  " />
```

Here we go with an enhanced version.
*In this version I removed unused stuff, set an appropriate event handler and shortened the syntax slightly*

```js
function callSum(id) {

    var sum = document.getElementById("sum" + id).value,
        vat = document.getElementById("vat" + id).value,
        sumallVal;

    $('.sumall').each(function () {

        /* get the value */
        sumallVal = $(this).val();

        $('.vatall').each(function () {

            /* set the value */
            $( $(this).val() == 0 ? "#vatTotalZero" : "#vatTotal" ).val( sumallVal )

        });

    });

}


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.sumall.form-control').on('input', function() {
        // get number id directly from string id by deleting all non numbers
        callSum( this.id.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '') );
    })

});
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class="col-sm-1">
        <!-- <input type="text" name="sum[]" id="sum1" onfocus="callSum(1)" class="sumall form-control" /> -->
        <input type="text" name="sum[]" id="sum1" class="sumall form-control" />
    </td>
    <td class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="text" name="vat[]" id="vat1" class="vatall form-control  " />
    </td>
</tr>
<br>
<br>
<label>All Sums without VAT (vat 0)</label>
<input type="text" name="vatTotalZero" id="vatTotalZero" class="form-control  " />
<br>
<br>
<label>All Sums with VAT (vat > 0)</label>
<input type="text" name="vatTotal" id="vatTotal" class="form-control  " />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```